# Periodically invoking of c# application using job in SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to invoke a c# application based on SQL server database. I have name's column in database. I want to check if there is any name present in the database then every after 1 hr my C# application should get invoked. I am asked to use a "job" concept in SQL server. Is it possible to perform this operation?

Answer (score 0):

Job schedules are designed to do maintenance staffs. They actually do something periodicall, but the things they do is about backups, running T-SQL jobs, CleanUp and etc. I don't think doing this by an SQL job agent be a good solution.

If you want to check db in a constant interval, then you could simply write an intermediate app (windows service or a console App) and check your db changes every 1 hr. If your desired changes happened then invoke your C# application.

Answer (score 0):

You could call a windows application using [a shell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx). You could do it in an [SQL server job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx) or in a [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

Hope I helped!